# extend line in median and iqr graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make an IQR plot with no min or max and I just want to display the median and IQR. The reason is I am working with sensitive data and showing outliers might identify participants. I have been able to create a version of the plot below but as you can see the "-" that represents the median does not stretch all the way across the bars. Is it possible to get the "-" to be the length of each bar? Other packages to answer the question are welcome, also acceptable is to have the plot made from aggregate or raw data.

```
   library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)



median_IQR <- function(x) {
  data.frame(y = median(x), # Median
             ymin = quantile(x)[2], # 1st quartile
             ymax = quantile(x)[4])  # 3rd quartile
}

iris <- mutate(iris, let = rep(c("a","b"), nrow(iris)/2))

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, color = let, fill=let ))

posn.d <- position_dodge(width=0.5)

 p + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar",
               fun.data = median_IQR, 
               position = 'dodge') + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", 
               fun = "median", 
               position = posn.d, 
               size = 3, 
               col = "black", 
               shape = "_")
```

[image: plot with dash]

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the first `stats_summary`solution, using the `geom function` instead of the `stat function`:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


iris <- mutate(iris, let = rep(c("a","b"), nrow(iris)/2))

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, color = let, fill=let ))+theme_bw()


    p +  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length),
                         stat = "summary",
                         fun.min = function(z) {quantile(z,0.25)},
                         fun.max = function(z) {quantile(z,0.75)},
                         fun = median, 
                         size=1)
```

To group the  points side by side

```
p+boxplot()
```

[image]

Otherwise

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution, do you think there is anyway to have this as a box plot instead of a line graph ?